# Eliminar repetidos en la unión de dos array's

Tags: java, array

Tengo un problema en hallar la solución de este ejercicio, si podéis ayudarme, os lo agradecería mucho.

Me pasan dos array's de enteros y debo devolver otro con la mezcla de ambos, obviando los repetidos.

Por ejemplo si el el array1 contiene estos números `{1,2,3,4,5,5,4}` y el array2 estos `{1,7,8,3,5}` el resultado de la mezcla seria este: `{2,4,7,8}`.

He conseguido eliminar los repetidos, pero si uno de los números aparece en los array's solo me borra uno.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
public class InicioArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[]= {4,8,2,9,21,5,13,16};
        int c[]= {21,16,14,8,12,16,7,22};
    
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        int b[]=Arrays2.sinRepeticion(a,c);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Arrays2{
    // Devuelve un nuevo arrays ordenado sin elementos duplicados
    // reduce el array al nuevo tamaño
    // No modifica el array pasado como parámetro
    public static int[] sinRepeticion(int[] array, int[] array2) {
        int aux[]=Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
        int aux2[]=Arrays.copyOf(array2, array2.length);
        int res[]=new int[array.length+array2.length];
        int aux3[]=new int [res.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < aux3.length / 2; i++) {
            aux3[i * 2] = aux[i];
            aux3[i * 2 + 1] = aux2[i];
        }
    
        Arrays.sort(aux3);
        Arrays.sort(aux2);
        Integer valor=aux3[0];
        int j=0;
        
        for (int i=0;i<aux3.length;i++) 
        
          if (valor!=aux3[i]) {
              res[j++]=valor;
              valor=aux3[i];
          }
         
        res[j++]=valor;
        
        aux3=Arrays.copyOf(res,j);
    
    return aux3;
    }
}
```

Comment: resolviste?, te sirvieron las respuestas? Puedes darle tu voto a las q te fueron utiles y marcar como aceptada la q mas te haya gustado, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Primero creamos un arreglo cuyo tamaño va a ser igual a la suma de los tamaños de los arreglos originales:

```
int tam = arregloA.length + arregloB.length;
int[] ArregloC = new int[tam];
```

Después llenamos este nuevo arreglo con los elementos de los arreglos originales.

Para no complicarnos tanto hacemos primero un **ciclo for** que copie en el nuevo arreglo cada elemento de **arregloA** y posteriormente hacemos otro **ciclo for** que copie los elementos de **arregloB** en el nuevo arreglo. Este paso por supuesto puede ser más optimizado:

```
int indice = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < arregloA.length; i++)
{
   arregloC[indice] = arregloA[i];
   indice++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < ArregloB.length; i++)
{
   arregloC[indice] = arregloB[i];
   indice++;
}
```

Ya tenemos todos los elementos de los dos arreglos originales copiados en el nuevo arreglo ahora procedemos a eliminar los duplicados.

Para eso usamos la estructura de datos **HashSet** la cual al recibir una lista automáticamente elimina los duplicados:

```
Set<Integer> NoDuplicados = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arregloC));
```

Comment: Me parece que el problema plantea eliminar elementos en caso de que ambos arreglos lo compartan, si un arreglo tiene elementos repetidos pero no se encuentra en el otro tan solo lo reduce a 1 elemento

Comment: No creo, fíjate en su pregunta para que veas que el tiene en el mismo arreglo elementos duplicados

Answer (score 1):

Son dos partes, una es la "union" que ya tienes, que en sentido estricto es la *diferencia simétrica* `A⊖B`; la otra es la manejo de duplicados:

```
   /* Regresa en orden ascendente 
    * los valores únicos de un arreglo de enteros distintos de cero */
   public static int[] valoresUnicos(int[] a){
      Arrays.sort(a);
      int j=0; // Indice para inserción
      int t[] = new int[a.length]; // Arreglo temporal mide igual que el arreglo original
      for( int i=0; i<a.length-1; i++ ) // Recorremos hasta el penúltimo elemento
         if( a[i] != a[i+1] ) // Si no esta repetido
            t[j++] = a[i];    // Se inserta el número
      t[j++] = a[a.length-1]; // El último elemento siempre se inserta
            
      /* El arreglo se inicia automáticamente con ceros,
         si hubo repeticiones quedarán ceros al final del arreglo */
      int max = t.length; // Donde se encuentra el primer cero, suponemos que no hay
      for( int i=0; i<t.length; i++ )
         if( t[i]==0 ){
            max = i;
            break;
         }
      return Arrays.copyOf(t, max); // Regresamos hasta donde no hay ceros
   }
```

La idea es pasar, por ejemplo el arreglo `[3,1,1,2,3]` a `[1,1,2,3,3]` a `[1,2,3,0,0]` a `[1,2,3]`.

La ventaja es que esta función la puedes aplicar antes, durante o después de encontrar `A⊖B`.

Comment: No hay un solo arreglo original sino 2

Comment: @Japv, por eso la función, es reusable.

Comment: Si entendí bien en tu solución asumes que ya la unión está hecha?

Answer (score 0):

Para esto me ayude de un buscador secuencial,(el código esta comentado donde explico también mi solución) Mi solución es primeramente crear un array auxiliar del tamaño de la suma de los 2 array (por si no hay algún repetido) luego buscar en el segundo array si tiene algún elemento del primero  en caso de que no tenga agregamos al auxiliar y aumentamos un contador(sera el tamaño del array que devolveremos) por que la idea es añadir los que no se repiten. Con la misma lógica buscamos en el primer array que no tenga ningún elemento del segundo array. Finalmente nuestro array que devolveremos lo inicializamos con el contador de elemento que no se repiten y mediante un bucle agregamos del array Aux al array que devolveremos los primeros n que seria el contador del tamaño del array

```
public static int[] sinRepeticion(int[] array, int[] array2) {
    // inicializar array a devolver despues definimos su tamaño
    int sinRepetidos[] ;
    //array auxiliar
    int aux3[] = new int[array.length + array2.length];
    int nroArrayAux = 0;

    // Recorrer el primer array donde buscara si algun elemento esta en array2
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (buscar(array2, array[i])==-1) {// Si no encontro(-1)en array2 agregar a aux3
            aux3[nroArrayAux]=array[i];
            nroArrayAux++;//aumentar el tamaño de contador de aux3
        }
    }
    //Con la misma logiga recorrer el array2 
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        if (buscar(array, array2[i])==-1) {// Si no encontro en array agregar a aux
            aux3[nroArrayAux]=array2[i];
            nroArrayAux++;
        }
    }
    //Ahora añadimos a nuestro array que devolveremos ya con su tamaño y orfnado
    sinRepetidos = new int[nroArrayAux];
    for(int i=0;i<nroArrayAux;i++){
        sinRepetidos[i]=aux3[i];//añadimos los que no se repditen
    }
    //Ordenamos el array
    Arrays.sort(sinRepetidos);

    return sinRepetidos ; /// complejidad algoritmica cuadratica
}
```

Modulo del buscador secuencial

```
    public static int buscar(int[] array, int nro) {
    int encontrado = -1;
    int index = 0;
    while (index < array.length) {
        if(array[index] == nro){
            encontrado = index;
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return encontrado;
}
```

Comment: Y si es el mismo array el que tiene el elemento duplicado, sin tener que buscar en el otro?

Comment: Funciona para la entrada: *a[]= {4,8,2,9,21,5,13,16} y c[]={21,16,14,8,12,16,7,22};* pero no para el ejemplo inicial: *{1,2,3,4,5,5,4} y {1,7,8,3,5}* Salida esperada *{2,4,7,8}* tu algoritmo -> *{2,4,4,7,8}*. Hay que eliminar los duplicados en el array que devuelve. Igual ya hiciste la parte más compleja.

Answer (score 0):

El algoritmo es bastante simple de entender va paso a paso, la 'complejidad' esta en los métodos. *(no modifico los originales según lo pedido en la pregunta)*

```
public static int[] unionDosArraysClean(int[] uno, int[] dos) {
    int[] copiaUno = Arrays.copyOf(uno, uno.length);
    int[] copiaDos = Arrays.copyOf(dos, dos.length);
    int[] union; // para los elementos únicos de ambos arrays
    //Algunos casos especiales: si son iguales: Array vacío
    if(uno.equals(dos)) return new int[0];
    if(uno.length == 0) return trimDuplicates(copiaDos);
    if(dos.length == 0) return trimDuplicates(copiaUno);
    // Eliminar duplicados en uno[]
    copiaUno = trimDuplicates(copiaUno);
    // Eliminar duplicados en dos[]
    copiaDos = trimDuplicates(copiaDos);
    // Unir ambos en un único array 'union[]'
    union = new int[copiaUno.length+copiaDos.length];
    System.arraycopy(copiaUno, 0, union, 0, copiaUno.length);
    System.arraycopy(copiaDos, 0, union, copiaUno.length, copiaDos.length);
    // eliminar duplicados de union[]
    int[] diferencia = killDuplicates(union);
    return diferencia;
}
```

**Primer** método **trimDuplicates(int[] arr)** ordena; elimina los duplicados, para [1,1,2,3] genera [1,2,3] y retorna un array del tamaño correcto.

```
private static int[] trimDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    if(arr.length == 0) return new int[0];
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int index = 0;      
    int[] arrClean = new int[arr.length];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < arrClean.length-1 ; i++) {
        if(arr[i] != arr[i+1]){
            arrClean[index]= arr[i];
            index++;
        }
    }
    /*  agregar el ultimo elemento del array original
     *  index++ para indicar la cantidad correcta de elementos únicos agregados 
     * */
    if(arr.length > 0) {
        arrClean[index++]= arr[arr.length-1];
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(arrClean, index);
}
```

**Segundo** método: ordena; elimina todos los elementos duplicados, es decir para [1,1,2,3] genera [2,3] y retorna un array del tamaño correcto.

```
private static int[] killDuplicates(int[] union) {  
    Arrays.sort(union);
    int[] diferencia = new int[union.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < union.length-1; i++) {
        if(union[i] == union[i+1]) {
            // elimina todos los repetidos
            while(i < union.length-1 && union[i] == union[i+1]) { 
                i++;
            }
        }else if(union[i] != union[i+1]) {
            diferencia[index] = union[i];
            index++;
        }
    }
    if(index != 0) // por si ambos son iguales 
        diferencia[index++] = union[union.length-1];
    return Arrays.copyOf(diferencia, index);
}
```

Todos los métodos deben estar en la misma clase hay dos private que solo se pueden usan dentro de la clase, hay que importar: `import java.util.Arrays;`